# Intuos creative stylus for iPad use on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, drawing

I saw the Intuos creative stylus for the iPad, and as much as I like it, I am not a fan of having to purchase a new Mac product just to use a pen that works with the iPad only...

Is there a pen out there that works like the Intuos creative stylus pen for iPad that would work with a MacBook Pro? I've heard of using the MagicMouse, but I'm looking for the same concept as the Intuos creative stylus for iPad, where the stylus would connect via a bluetooth, with the same abilities of an Inkling, drawing anywhere...

Is this even possible? Paying for it isn't an issue, it's just I can't justify $400+ for a iPad, the software, and the pen itself...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

Certainly not possible, and no such product exists. The MacBook screen is not a touch or pressure input device, unlike the iPad.

## Long answer:

The iPad stylus uses touch events to communicate position and Bluetooth to communicate pressure. With the MacBook, no positional tracking device exists in the screen.

Getting around this limitation would involve adding a sensor layer to the glass. This would be a hardware modification and you'd end up writing a lot of software to support it, too.

Comment: Too bad, because Inkling seems to of gotten past that issue, but it still would be nice if you could "draw" on the screen using the inkling concept... if you get what I mean?

Comment: Inkling doesn't really do the same thing - it tracks the position of the stylus relative to the tracker, but it doesn't have to map that to a screen position. The ink doesn't have to "know" where it goes because it's entirely physical, and the dimensions of the digital sketch only need to exist as internal, relative measurements. An Inkling file defines its boundaries by the furthest points in the drawing from the receiver.

Comment: Now, something LIKE Inkling COULD work, hypothetically. Calibration would be a bit of a nightmare, mind, and also keep in mind that the glass on a touchscreen is substantially thicker and resistant to pressure, impact, scratches, and wear than your MacBook's glass

Answer (score 0):

The MacBooks trackpad is basically the iPhone touchscreen without a display. You would be able to use it as a dumb stylus with your laptops trackpad but I haven't found anyone writing firmware for any of the pressure sensitive styluses.

https://tenonedesign.com/inklet.php

This software is as close as I could find.